# Using Steeltoe DiscoveryHttpMessageHandler with FlurlClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, flurl, steeltoe

I am looking to switch our HttpClients to use Flurl.  However, our HttpClient is currently configured to use Service Discovery via Steeltoe.  Basically it's doing this in ConfigureServices:

```
   services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>().AddHttpMessageHandler<DiscoveryHttpMessageHandler>();
```

DiscoveryHttpMessageHandler is a custom http message handler in the Steeltoe library (https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS)

How do I access the IHttpClientBuilder with Flurl so I can add this same message hander?  Or is there another clean way with Flurl to add a custom message handler for every HttpClient/FlurlClient created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to add a custom message handler with Flurl (such as with a custom [factory](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory)), but since you're already using `IHttpClientFactory`, I think the easiest path to get what you want (and the one I'd recommend) is to continue injecting `HttpClient` into your services as you're doing and wrap them with Flurl inside the service:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly IFlurlClient _flurlClient;

    public MyService(HttpClient httpClient) {
        _flurlClient = new FlurlClient(httpClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: We already went through the process of creating a custom factory for Flurl that creates the discovery message handler, but I kinda like your solution too.  I will have to pass it by my teammates and see which way they like best.  Thank you!